# Using $3$ points create new coordinate system and create array of points on $XY$ plane in original coordinate system

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

This is my first post on stack exchange :) Basically what I am trying to do is something called palletizing in the robotics world.  Given $3$ points I would like to create a new coordinate system and then create a lattice structure of points on the new $XY$ plane, but I would like the final coordinates of the points on the $XY$ plane to be in the original coordinate system.  I found this link [HERE](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/309606) which does almost exactly what id like.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach to your problem. Let  $A$, $B$, and $C$, be the 3 points of interest.

**1.** Define your coordinate system by three orthogonal unit vectors with $A$ as the origin. Perhaps defined as

$V_1 = \frac{B-A}{\|B-A\|}$

$V_2 = \frac{V_1 \times (C-A)}{\|V_1 \times (C-A)\|}$

$V_3 = V_1 \times V_2$

**2.** Define your lattice in the new coordinate system.

**3.** Calculate the transform between your original coordinate system and your new coordinate system defined by $V_1, V_2,$ and $V_3$.

**4.** Transform your points in the lattice from your new coordinate system to your old coordinate system.